# setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage

Tags: java, web-services, jboss, jax-ws, jboss5.x

I'm trying to deploy some web services in a WAR application on JBoss 5.1.0.

I have created the source files from an existing wsdl using JAX-WS tool `wsgen`. This created the Service files and @XmlType annotated clases that would act as request and response wrappers.

This classes worked well on JBoss 4.2.3, but when moving to JBoss 5.1.0, I get this exception.

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage

My configuration:

- Windows XP SP3 (but getting the same on Vista, as well as on Linux)
- Sun JDK 1.6.0_17
- JBoss 5.1.0 GA for jdk6

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are a few thing that might go wrong, so I will tell you what helped in my case (analogous to yours, I was using JDK 1.6.0_13).

The problem lies in JARs mismatch. First of all make sure JBoss is using JDK 1.6 check your JAVA_HOME env. variable. Secondly make sure your classes are compiled using JDK 1.6. If you run your project from Eclipse make sure Eclipse is using right JDK, the same if you run JBoss from Eclipse.

I guess your have it right, so there comes some magic. Running client **do not** use libraries from $JBOSS_HOME/client, but use only the ones provided in $JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed. Obviously if you are using any other JAX-WS-unrelated API like JPA or EJB or Servlets you can add them to the classpath, but use **only** lib/endorsed JAX-WS JARs.

It helped in my particular situation in case of JBoss 5.1, in earlier versions of JBoss a few other tricks worked, for instance try to add java option 
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true or/and -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed when starting your client and JBoss.

Comment: Thanks Piotr! After all, the problem was that I was starting JBoss from within eclipse, with it's automatic launch config... which does not pass the -Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed param. After adding this (as well as running JBoss from the run.bat script) it worked fine. Thanks again! (you deserve more than just one vote up from me :) )

Comment: Tried both "-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true" and "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=$JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed", did not work in 4.2.3.GA.

Comment: i think this type of workaround is pretty bad, as it could have impact on others deployed applications, and make the industrialization process more difficult. The scope should be limited to application package (like classloader config/filters).

Answer (score 24):

I had the same issue with an upgrade from JBoss 4.2.2 and found the answer in the
[JBoss 5.1.0 Release Notes](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossas/tags/JBoss_5_1_0_GA/build/docs/readme.html#Compatibility):

> JBossAS 5.0.0.GA can be compiled with both Java5 & Java6. The Java5 compiled binary is our primary/recommended binary distribution. It has undergone rigorous testing and can run under both a Java 5 and a Java 6 runtime. When running under Java 6 you need to manually copy the following libraries from the JBOSS_HOME/client directory to the JBOSS_HOME/lib/endorsed directory, so that the JAX-WS 2.0 apis supported by JBossWS are used:
>
> - jbossws-native-saaj.jar
> - jbossws-native-jaxrpc.jar
> - jbossws-native-jaxws.jar
> - jbossws-native-jaxws-ext.jar

I was using the distribution of JBoss 5.1.0 build with Java 5 (running on JDK 1.6.0_20) and sure enough copying these JARs into the endorsed directory fixed the issue. We're not using the version compiled for Java 6 because of the note:

> It should be noted however that the Java 6 compiled distribution of JBoss AS 5 is still in experimental stage.

Answer (score 7):

It could be due to conflict issue with `SAAJ` jar. Copy `Jboss`'s `Saaj` jar from `{Jboss_HOME}/LIB` to `{JBOSS_HOME}/lib/endorsed`. I hope this would help in resolving issue,

Comment: Copying the jboss-saaj.jar from the jboss/server/<config>/lib directory to jboss/lib/endorsed did the trick for me on jboss-4.2.3.GA

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you launch `JBoss` with the `jvm` options pointing to the endorsed libs.
This is not configured by default if you launch `JBoss` from Eclipse, using `WTP`, though it is if you launch `JBoss` from the command line.

You can add the following to the VM arguments of the Launch Configuration:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs="${JBOSS_HOME}\jboss-as\lib\endorsed"
```

Comment: Good to note that eclipse won't expand $JBOSS_HOME in a run target's jvm options.

Comment: Wow I ended up back here again today and don't even remember the first time!

Answer (score 2):

try following jars to your jboss/lib/endorsed folder

```
jbossws-native-jaxws.jar
jbossws-native-jaxrpc.jar
jbossws-native-saaj.jar
jbossws-native-saaj.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

My project was simply based on :

- CXF 2.5.0 (Soap WebService Consumer)
- WAR assembly (no EAR)
- no jboss-web
- no jboss-classloading
- no changes in jboss/lib/endorsed (only xalan, serializer, xercesImpl)
- running on jboss-4.2.1.GA + JDK 1.6

What it worked for me was simply to add thoses maven dependencies, next to CXF :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
        <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Hope it will help !

Answer (score 0):

I copied necessary lib (saaj-impl in my case) to my war from cxf distribution and turned on jboss classloader isolation with the file /WEB-INF/jboss-classloader.xml of the following content:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    domain="MyDomain"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

Hope this help to somebody.

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error in the client while running a client application you need to follow similar steps in addition to those in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738542/setproperty-must-be-overridden-by-all-subclasses-of-soapmessage/1738569#1738569):

1. Determine which instance of the JVM is running the application.  In my case I had standalone applications using the JDK and applets using the JRE.  This will be somewhere like `/path/jre/bin/`
2. Add the jars from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738542/setproperty-must-be-overridden-by-all-subclasses-of-soapmessage/1738569#1738569) to `path/jre/lib/endorsed`.  I had to create the `endorsed` directory.

This tells the VM to load the jboss specific implementations before the java language defaults.  This happens in the bootstrap class loader, well before the jars in the classpath are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is the link to this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-2418

Answer (score 0):

My server configuration is Jboss AS 4.2.1 GA and like below, it works;

Libraries that I used at lib\endorsed;

- JAXWS2.1.1_20070501
- jbossws-native-jaxrpc
- jbossws-native-jaxws
- jbossws-native-jaxws-ext
- jbossws-native-saaj
- serializer
- xalan
- xercesImpl

Answer (score 0):

I use Jboss AS 4.3.
In my case, i removed from "deploy" folder the "jbossws.sar".

See this issue: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBWS-2821

Answer (score 0):

Adding saaj-impl to my web app's lib folder fixed this error. I am using JBoss 4.2.3 and CXF 2.4.10.