# setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage error using JBoss 4.2.2GA

Tags: eclipse, web-services, jboss, jboss-4.2.x

I was trying to implement web services using the jboss. I had written server side files and tried to generate the wsdl file by placing the files in deploy folder. On running the JBoss(4.2.2GA),  wsdl is getting created and I am able to access the wsdl by giving the link in internet explorer. Then I created the source files by using the **Web Services/Web Service Client Wizard** in Eclipse.
When I was trying to call the exposed methods from the client side code, am getting the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.ws.core.jaxws.SOAPFaultHelperJAXWS] SOAP request exception
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
at javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.java:424)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:67)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:207)
at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:185)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:389)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:272)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:189)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:122)
at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.EndpointServlet.service(EndpointServlet.java:84)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I had found this link which deals with the same topic 'http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/jbossws-issues/2009-May/005421.html'

I am not understanding what to do.
Need help !!!
Thanks
-Aj

Comment: possible duplicate of [setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738542/setproperty-must-be-overridden-by-all-subclasses-of-soapmessage)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had seen the comments given in it and it hasn't helped me. I am using JBoss 4.2.2GA.  Do you recommend upgrade to JBoss 5.1 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue has been resolved.
**Configuration I used:**

1. Eclipse IDE 3.3.0
2. JBoss-4.2.2 GA

3.Libraries used in lib/endorsed :

- jboss-saaj.jar
- jboss-jaxws.jar
- jboss-jaxrpc.jar
- jaxb-api-2.1.9.jar
- xercesImpl.jar
- xalan.jar
- serializer.jar

Make sure the VM configuration is given for the client file from which the call to the wsdl exposed methods is done.
That is, including of '-Djava.endorsed.dirs=jboss-4.2.2.GA\lib\endorsed' at VM arguments.

I tried running the client file by having saaj.jar and jboss-saaj.jar.  It was giving rise to conflicts, and on removing saaj.jar, the problem was solved and the issue resolved.

Thanks
-Aj