# JBoss 5.1.0 GA and EJB3

Tags: web-services, jboss, ejb

I want to understand does JBoss 5.1.0 GA server supports EJB 3.0 ?

Because I have developed a EJB 3 webservices application and deployed the war into JBoss 5.1.0 GA server.

When I tested in SOAP UI , I have got below error.

```
org.jboss.ws.WSException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
  at org.jboss.ws.WSException.rethrow(WSException.java:68)
  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:336)
  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.doPost(RequestHandlerImpl.java:205)
  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleHttpRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:131)
  at org.jboss.wsf.common.servlet.AbstractEndpointServlet.service(AbstractEndpointServlet.java:85)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: setProperty must be overridden by all subclasses of SOAPMessage
  at javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.java:439)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPMessageImpl.<init>(SOAPMessageImpl.java:87)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.MessageFactoryImpl.createMessage(MessageFactoryImpl.java:169)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.createSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.java:317)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.toSOAPMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.java:235)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.exceptionToFaultMessage(SOAPFaultHelperJAXRPC.java:213)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.jaxrpc.SOAP11BindingJAXRPC.createFaultMessageFromException(SOAP11BindingJAXRPC.java:61)
  at org.jboss.ws.core.CommonSOAPBinding.bindFaultMessage(CommonSOAPBinding.java:671)
  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.processRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:496)
  at org.jboss.wsf.stack.jbws.RequestHandlerImpl.handleRequest(RequestHandlerImpl.java:295)
  ... 24 more
```

Any assistance on this issue is highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question: According to the german [wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_JavaBeans) entry of Enterprise Java Beans, yes EJB3.0 was available for JEE5.
Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738542/setproperty-must-be-overridden-by-all-subclasses-of-soapmessage) article, your error could come from a problem with a dependency / library, but I never got this problem so I am not sure.